# Kotlin Webclient Spring boot - Type definition error: [simple type, class org.springframework.data.domain.Page]

Tags: spring, kotlin, webclient

Hello i am getting this error with webclient:

```
Type definition error: [simple type, class org.springframework.data.domain.Page]}
```

The code looks like this:

```
    suspend fun getData(params: String): Page<MyClass> {
    return try {
        webClient.get()
            .uri(url) { it.query(params).build() }
            .header(header, TenantContext.getTenant())
            .retrieve()
            .awaitBody()
```

I tried to fix it with this it works but I don't like this solution at all isn't there better way to do so?

```
class CustomPageImpl<T> : PageImpl<T> {
@JsonCreator(mode = JsonCreator.Mode.PROPERTIES)
constructor(
    @JsonProperty("content") content: List<T>?, @JsonProperty("number") number: Int,
    @JsonProperty("size") size: Int, @JsonProperty("totalElements") totalElements: Long?,
    @JsonProperty("pageable") pageable: JsonNode?, @JsonProperty("last") last: Boolean,
    @JsonProperty("totalPages") totalPages: Int, @JsonProperty("sort") sort: JsonNode?,
    @JsonProperty("numberOfElements") numberOfElements: Int
) : super(
    content!!, PageRequest.of(number, 1), 10
)

constructor(content: List<T>?, pageable: Pageable?, total: Long) : super(
    content!!, pageable!!, total
)

constructor(content: List<T>?) : super(content!!)
constructor() : super(ArrayList<T>())
```

}